# how do I attack Ubuntu with Kali when ports are close?

Tags: 14.04, kali, portscan

I installed Ubuntu 14 and Kali. I want to attack Ubuntu with `nmap` (Kali). I scan with `nmap -sS ip -O` but all 1000 ports are closed. Can I do an attack? Which attack? (I install Bro IDS on Ubuntu, it should detect attack, i have not done it yet.)

Comment: I install ubuntu and kali on vm workstation. ubuntu and kali connect with range IP and NAt network connection.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I do an attack?

Yes. You already did didn't you? Or did you mean: how do I gain access when all ports are closed? Well then ... not through those ports. You need something to enter in from. Likely internet (80) is open on the machine.

> Which attack?

Find an exploit and abuse it. In regards to internet: find out what browser you use (:)) on that system and find an exploit for that browser (good luck finding one) and see if you can get a command prompt through that.

- [Mozilla](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/known-vulnerabilities/) has a list of known-vulnerabilities for their products.
- So does Google for [Chrome](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-1224/product_id-15031/opec-1/Google-Chrome.html).
- And [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/bugs).

Good luck though. Social engineering is the easier of these 2.

Comment: _internet (80)_ should be “web” most likely…

Comment: _You already did didn't you?_ i laughed hard at this :)

Comment: *Good luck though. Social engineering is the easier of these 2.* Really? I've always found it totally impossible to social-engineer myself; someone always seems to tip the other guy off as to what's going on before I can do anything malicious.

Comment: @NickWeinberg yes it is! All he has to do is put a knife to his own throat and force himself to provide his admin accounts password ;)

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, It is very hard to exploit default OS, you may need to install any service and configure it keeping loophole or otherwise ,
You may setup your own lab like : dvwa , hackxor, sqllol , bodgeit, kioptrix, exploit-kb, wackopicko, metasploitable2 , etc.